Reporting progress out of CUDA function in Python (Numba)
I have a long-running CUDA function and would like to report its progress periodically.
I'm trying to use a pinned array along with streams like in https://towardsdatascience.com/cuda-by-numba-examples-7652412af1ee
But, even though the GPU is loaded and the values should be changed, the reported progress is always 0.
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda
import threading

@cuda.jit
def gpu_function(progress):
    progress[0] = 17
    for i in range(1000000000):
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            progress[0] = 17 + i // 1000

def monitor_progress(progress_gpu, progress_host, stream):
    while True:
        progress_gpu.copy_to_host(progress_host, stream=stream)
        print(f"Progress: {progress_host[0]}")
        time.sleep(1)

progress_host = np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int32)

with cuda.pinned(progress_host):
    stream = cuda.stream()
    progress_gpu = cuda.to_device(progress_host, stream=stream)

    gpu_function[256, 1, stream](progress_gpu)

    monitor_thread = threading.Thread(target=monitor_progress, args=(progress_gpu, progress_host, stream))
    monitor_thread.start()

    stream.synchronize()


This is broken in about 5 different ways (if it would actually work, which I doubt). Operations in the same streams are, by design, serialized with respect to one another. So putting polling memory copies into the same stream guarantees that they will run the after preceding  kernel .

@talonmies thank you, may you please advise me how to implement reporting the progress in a proper way?

As I said, I don't believe there is a "proper" way to make this work (or at least not anything like what you are envisaging) and certainly not in Numba Python
